# Best practice for setting a selected row in a database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have one table called *addresses* in my database which stores **all** the shipping addresses which belong to the user. A user can select their primary address.

My question is, which is better practice:

- To create a separate table for the primary address selection (e.g. a table called *primaryaddress* with a *user_id* and *address_id* foreign keys. If a row exists in this table, it links to the primary address of the user)?

or

- To create a value in the *addressses* table which keeps track of the primary address (a boolean called *primary* which can either be true or false)?

Comment: I don't think that there's a 'best'. Both methods are fine

Comment: This is a question about integrity (separate table) vs simplicity (boolean column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would add an `AddressType` field on the `Address` table and make a unique constraint against the `UserId` and the address type so that the user can have many addresses but only one of each type i.e Primary, Secondary, Other etc.

This lets you have the option to have other address types in the future and doesnt lock you down to a boolean flag. Then if you decide a user can have many primary addresses you can remove the constraint and implement logic to handle this.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks, I didn't think of this.